# OneToOne relationship, keep only foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to establish a OneToOne relationship between two entities (`PartnerDetails` and `JWTData`. How ever, I only want to store the primary key of `PartnerDetails` entity in `JWTData`, not the whole object, like this.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "partner_details")
public class PartnerDetails {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "partner_id")
  private String partnerId;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "partnerId")
  private JWTData jwtData;

}

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "jwt_data")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JWTData {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(targetEntity = PartnerDetails.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "partner_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_jwt_partnerdetails_partnerid"))
  private String partnerId;

  @NotBlank
  private String secret;
}
```

But after fetching the `JWTData` using repository, Hibernate cannot convert the String to a `PartnerDetails`. Can this be done using any other way?

Comment: Please add table schema

Comment: You need to have `PartnerDetails` object in `JWTData` class to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add `PartnerDetails` to `JWTData` then JPA will know to use only the id. JPA is an Object Oriented framework so you should reference objects unless you specifically want a field. JPA handles the details for you. Note that in this configuration `JWTData` in the "owning" entity because of the `mappedBy` annotation, therefore only setting the `partnerDetails` field in a `JWTData` instance will persist the relationship to the database. The `jwtData` field in `PartnerDetails` is for query results only and makes for a `Bidirectional` instead of a `Unidirectional` mapping. Also, because of this, having a `CascadeType` setting generally only makes sense on the owning entity since it is the one handling the database updates and deletes.

When playing around with JPA be sure to turn on the SQL output so that you know what is actually happening.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "partner_details")
public class PartnerDetails {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "partner_id")
  private String partnerId;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "partnerDetails")
  private JWTData jwtData;


@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "jwt_data")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JWTData {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  // even though it looks like the entire class it's only saving the id to the database.
  @OneToOne
  private PartnerDetails partnerDetails;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.